# UI elements not displaying where they actually are on storyboard in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, xcode8

[though the elements show, they don't show in the proper location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODF94.png)

When I put UI elements in to the storyboard on this app that I'm working on they do not show up in the right location. I can edit them, move them, manipulate them... but all of it shows up lower than where they are actually located. then on this second viewcontroller that I have created, the header from the first viewcontroller is now showing up over there.

Not really sure if there is a way that I can reset the storyboards or get this to clean up at all.

thanks.

Comment: Have you setup constraints properly, either by AutoLayout Constraints or classic Autoresizing setting?

Comment: have u tried to clean up your project with deleting your derived data and clean and build again ? Close Xcode and all the stuff.

Comment: @OOPer I had set up some yes. I just came back to it and was looking at the constraints. I think what it was was a stack view that I had accidentally added when I didn't know what the button did. I deleted that and now everything lines up. It was that... or stackoverflow just fixed it for me.

Comment: @Osman how does one delete derived data? I closed xcode and restarted my computer and neither of those fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two buttons were in a stack view with constraints that were throwing them off. Once I removed the stack view and laid out the buttons without the extra view they worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

- delete all your constraints first from the left hand side of the story board.
- run the app and see how it looks
- now, set contraints for each widget one by one properly and give it a try